# Nesting foreach loops with PDO statements

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I'm trying to nest foreach loops with PDO statements (this previously worked for me in mysql,btw). The first example works and the second one doesn't. However I'd prefer not to run a SQL query every time (isn't that the point of PDO?) and would prefer to use something more like example 2. However, it doesn't 'nest' the loop inside the other, it seems, rather it runs the first then the next.

Example 1)

```
    foreach($db->query('SELECT country FROM db GROUP BY `country`') as $row1) {
echo $row1['country']."<br/>";

    foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM db') as $row2) {
        if ($row1['country']==$row2['country']){
            echo $row2['name']."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Example 2)

```
$cntry = $db->query('SELECT country FROM db GROUP BY `country` ');
$rslts = $db->query('SELECT * FROM db');

foreach ($cntry as $row1) {

    echo "<div id='".$row1['country']."'>".$row1['country']."<br/>";

    foreach($rslts as $row2) {
        if ($row1['country']==$row2['country']){
            echo $row2['name']."<br/>";
            }

        };
echo "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to "rewind" the result-set? or something? I have looked at similar examples but they are not that clear

Comment: I have found two ways that this works for me: 1) adding ->fetchAll(); to the end of the query 2) adding $rslts->execute(); at the end of the loop that is only return the result once, "re-winding" the result.

Any comments on why these work, which is best-practice etc would be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

> (isn't that the point of PDO?)

No. The point of PDO is to send your query to database server and to return the results back. But PDO cannot reduce the number of queries executed.

So, here goes the proper solution:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT country, name FROM db ORDER BY country, name');
$data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

foreach ($data as $country => $row)
{
    echo $country."<br/>\n";
    foreach ($row as $name)
    {
        echo $name."<br/>\n";
    }
}
```

As a matter of fact, `fetchAll()` is just a **syntax sugar** for the code like this:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

it just creates a **regular PHP array** out of query result. And of course you can loop over this array as many times as you wish. Means you an **always** replace `fetchAll()` with manual looping over results, and of course you may group the results whatever way you wish.

While using `foreach` on **`$stmt`** is just a syntax sugar again, intended to confuse PHP users. Because `$stmt` is not an array but a way more complex structure.

Comment: Hi, What i meant by "isn't that the point of PDO" is that I don't keep having to query the database every instance. In no way did I mean what you are referring!! Thanks, I will try this

Comment: To avoid repeated query execution you have to program your code properly. PDO won't do it for you.

Comment: Either way, PDO cannot reduce number of queries executed.

Comment: I have updated my example 2 to show why I mention using the loops to build markup. Can you show me please how your example can nest the second set of results inside the first, in this case with a <div>??

Comment: I can see where to open the div, but not where to close it so that it nests the 'name' results within it!?

Comment: I see now. I'll post the solution soon

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but as I remember it would be like this

```
$cntry = $db->query('SELECT country FROM db GROUP BY `country` ')->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$rslts = $db->query('SELECT * FROM db')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

foreach ($cntry as $row1) {

echo $row1['country']."<br/>";

foreach($rslts as $row2) {
    if ($row1['country']==$row2['country']){
        echo $row2['name']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your example works but only if I take out PDO::FETCH_COLUMN

Comment: pure pdo I have used more that 1 year ago, so I start forgetting syntax :) dark side of ORM is make you forgetting syntax of low-level code